# How to get GIMP to unselect the initial background?

Tags: gimp, selections

[image]

How can I get GIMP to de-select the background in my attached picture?  Everytime I try to use Select None...nothing happens.

Comment: Your screenshot does not include the interesting part - the layers dialog. Can you add one that shows all the GIMP windows?

Comment: Hi NOAH, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Basing upon your image, it seems that you are referring to the [layer boundary](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-view-show-layer-boundary.html), which is the yellow dotted line that surrounds a layer in the image window (the selection boundary is grayed and keeps moving, like *"marching ants"*):

[image: boundaries]

You can hide the layer boundary by unchecking the flag *Show Layer Boundary* in *View* menu:

[image: View menu]

It should do the trick:

[image: boundary hidden]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've actually got a selection in force there!

The dots around the oar-like shapes are not GIMP's "marching ants" (which would indicate a selection) but something else - individual pixels and pairs of adjacent pixels either placed onto the image or left-over from some previous step. And they are not anti-aliasing pixels.

I think the most likely explanation is that those dots are artefacts which have been left by a less-than-perfect extraction of the shapes from some previous background.

However you got to this point, if the dots aren't on a separate layer, to extract the shapes onto a transparent background (which I presume is what you are trying to do) you will first need to erase the dots to white and then use Colours > Colour to alpha (white) to change the background to transparent.