# Yellow/black bordered region in layer

Tags: gimp

After many years of casual use, I'm still very new to GIMP. I've somehow managed to get a boundary around my shapes. If I try to move any shape it is truncated at the boundary.

[image]

What is this yellow and black border? How do I reset/remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is somehow related to *[How to get GIMP to unselect the initial background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62228/how-to-get-gimp-to-unselect-the-initial-background)*.

The size of your layer is represented by the [layer boundary](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-view-show-layer-boundary.html) also known as *marching ants*.

You can move the entire layer, and the part of the layer in the range of the [canvas size](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-image-resize.html) of image will be visible.

If you want to alter the content of the layer beyond the size of the layer itself (e.g. as result of a transformation), you must [resize](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-resize.html) the boundary of the layer (in case, [to the image size](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-resize-to-image.html)).

Answer (score 2):

These are layer boundaries - they limit the regions where pixels exist at the given layer. To simply not display the yellow dashed line, just untoggle `view->Show Layer Boudary` (this is a per image view option, `edit->preferences->Image Windows->Appearance->Show Layer Boundary`  to set the default).

If you want to paint outside that boundary, you have to extend the layer itself, not just make the dashed line invisible. Then, just do `Layer->Layer to Image Size` - and it will just work.